# I want to insert a blank page for duplex printing but only when the group is one page

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that will be used as a mass mailing.  I have a page break based on a group.  However, some grooups extend to a second page.  I would like all groups to have 2 pages for easier duplex printing.  In this case, I actually want blanks pages between the groups IF the group is less than 2 pages. I have tried setting that group pagebreak properties disabled using =IIF(Globals!PageNumber Mod 2 = 0, True, False), but get an error that pagenumber can only be used in report headers or footers.  I am using 2008 R2.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: What? Please elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

The PageNumber restriction is truly bogus - so irritating.

I would try to work around it by adding a Page Footer textbox with your expression (referencing PageNumber).  You can then refer to that textbox using the syntax:

`ReportItems!MyPageNumber.Value`